# How can I check if a Neo4j fulltext index exists?

Tags: neo4j

I have two indices on the same label and property; one fulltext index and one btree index. How can I check if the fulltext index exists or not?

According to https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/filtering-show/ I should be able to filter the output of `SHOW` using `YIELD` and `WHERE` but that doesn't seem to work with indices:

```
Invalid input 'Y': expected whitespace, comment, type of show output, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 14 (offset: 13))
"SHOW INDEXES YIELD name, type"
```

The following query works but issues a deprecation warning about `db.indexes`:

```
CALL db.indexes() YIELD name, type
WHERE name = "usernames" AND type = "FULLTEXT"
RETURN count(name) > 0
```

Comment: deprecation warning is just a message that db.indexes will be replaced or becomes obsolete in future release(s). I'm using Neo4j Server version: 4.1.5 (enterprise) and your query works.

Comment: Thanks, yes it works but deprecation warnings are usually a sign that something shouldn't be used. I'd prefer to use a proper solution and not have to revisit this in a few months time

Answer (score 0):

## Viewable list, (but not operable)

```
SHOW [ALL|BTREE] INDEX[ES] [BRIEF|VERBOSE [OUTPUT]]

SHOW ALL INDEX VERBOSE
```

### Errors when recreating an index?

Use ***IF NOT EXISTS***

```
CREATE INDEX usernames IF NOT EXISTS FOR (u:User) ON (u.username)
```

### Deprecation

Unfortunately, there is no *un-deprecated* way to get a list of indices which you can operate on as per your example. However, deprecation *does not* mean you shouldn't use it. Deprecation *usually* (in semantic versioning) means that the method will not be available, or will be significantly changed, in the next major release. Don't worry, Neo4j 5 is a ways off.

#### References

- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/